Apex test using ConnectApi stub mock consistently fails with no matching item error
I am attempting to mock ConnectApi.ContentHub.addRepsitoryItem with the built in apex stub method ConnectApi.ContentHub.setTestAddRepositoryItem and it consistently fails when I include the ConnectApi.BinaryInput parameter with the following error:

ConnectApiCallerTest.addItemTest  Fail     System.AssertException: Assertion Failed: No matching test result found for ContentHub.addRepositoryItem(String repositoryId, String repositoryFolderId, ConnectApi.ContentHubItemInput file, ConnectApi.BinaryInput fileData). Before calling this, call ContentHub.setTestAddRepositoryItem(String repositoryId, String repositoryFolderId, ConnectApi.ContentHubItemInput file, ConnectApi.BinaryInput fileData, ConnectApi.RepositoryFolderItem result) to set the expected test result.

I've simplified my code into a reproducible example ensuring ConnectApi.ContentHub.addRepositoryItem is called with the exact same parameters as ConnectApi.ContentHub.setTestAddRepositoryItem
I've determined it's the BinaryInput that's causing the error because the test passes if I remove the BinaryInput parameter from the method calls.
public with sharing class ConnectApiCaller {
    public static String repoId = '0XCRL0000003MiL4AU';
    public static String folderId = 'folderId';
    public static String itemTypeId = 'file';
    public static Map<String, String> fieldValues = new Map<String, String>{ 'name' => 'test' };
    public static Blob fileBody = Blob.valueOf('file');
    public static String fileType = 'text/plain';

    public static ConnectApi.RepositoryFolderItem addItem() {
        ConnectApi.ContentHubItemInput inputItem = new ConnectApi.ContentHubItemInput();
        inputItem.itemTypeId = itemTypeId;
        inputItem.fields = new List<ConnectApi.ContentHubFieldValueInput>();
        for (String key : fieldValues.keySet()) {
            ConnectApi.ContentHubFieldValueInput fieldValue = new ConnectApi.ContentHubFieldValueInput();
            fieldValue.name = key;
            fieldValue.value = fieldValues.get(key);
            inputItem.fields.add(fieldValue);
        }
        ConnectApi.BinaryInput binaryInput = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(fileBody, fileType, 'test.txt');
        return ConnectApi.ContentHub.addRepositoryItem(repoId, folderId, inputItem, binaryInput);
        // return ConnectApi.ContentHub.addRepositoryItem(repoId, folderId, inputItem); // uncomment this to see test passes without the ConnectApi.BinaryInput parameter
    }
}


@IsTest
private class ConnectApiCallerTest {
    @IsTest
    private static void addItemTest() {
        // given
        ConnectApi.ContentHubItemInput inputItem = new ConnectApi.ContentHubItemInput();
        inputItem.itemTypeId = ConnectApiCaller.itemTypeId;
        inputItem.fields = new List<ConnectApi.ContentHubFieldValueInput>();
        for (String key : ConnectApiCaller.fieldValues.keySet()) {
            ConnectApi.ContentHubFieldValueInput fieldValue = new ConnectApi.ContentHubFieldValueInput();
            fieldValue.name = key;
            fieldValue.value = ConnectApiCaller.fieldValues.get(key);
            inputItem.fields.add(fieldValue);
        }

        ConnectApi.RepositoryFolderItem newItem = new ConnectApi.RepositoryFolderItem();
        newItem.file = new ConnectApi.RepositoryFileSummary();
        newItem.file.id = 'newId';

        ConnectApi.BinaryInput binaryInput = new ConnectApi.BinaryInput(
            ConnectApiCaller.fileBody,
            ConnectApiCaller.fileType,
            'test.txt'
        );

        ConnectApi.ContentHub.setTestAddRepositoryItem(
            ConnectApiCaller.repoId,
            ConnectApiCaller.folderId,
            inputItem,
            binaryInput, // comment this out to see test pass without ConnectApi.BinaryInput parameter
            newItem
        );

        // when
        ConnectApi.RepositoryFolderItem result = ConnectApiCaller.addItem();

        // then
        System.assertEquals('newId', result.file.id);
    }
}

Is this a Salesforce bug or am I missing a key property of the BinaryInput salesforce uses to determine equality?

I submitted a case with Salesforce and they said ConnectApi.ContentHub.setTestAddRepositoryItem needs to be called with the same ConnectApi.BinaryInput object reference as ConnectApi.ContentHub.addRepositoryItem
This parameter behaves differently than the ConnectApi.ContentHubItemInput parameter which can be matched when the attribute values match, i.e. they don't need to be the same reference.
I asked Salesforce to make a bug ticket and to treat each of these parameters the same when determining equality, ideally matching by value and not reference.
